# Update Top 1 Row In SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql

I know that typically you would have an autonumber field - but in this instance there is not, and it honestly does not matter which row get's updated as long as it is only 1.

I have sample DDL like such one table that contains requested qty, and one table that contains avaliable qty.  I want to update `@Test1.amtonhand` with the value from `@Test2.amtonhand` and join on `@Test1.nrs=@Test2.nrs` but only update the 1 record in `@Test1`

How is this achieved in SQL Server 2008

```
    Declare @Test1 Table
(
    nrs varchar(100)
    ,amtrqst varchar(100)
    ,amtonhand varchar(100)
)

Declare @Test2 Table
(
    nrs varchar(100)
    ,amtonhand varchar(100)
)


Insert Into @Test1 (nrs, amtrqst) Values
('abc', '10'), ('abc', '12'), ('abc', '13'), ('def', '5'), ('def', '12')

Insert Into @Test2 (nrs, amtonhand) Values
('abc', '10'), ('def', '5')
```

**EDIT**
My desired results from the update would be

```
@Test1 --
abc, 10, 10
abc, 12
abc, 13
def, 5, 5
def, 12
```

Comment: You should add in desired results.

Comment: @sp_BlitzErik - see my edit, does that help?

Comment: But, `abc`, `10`, `NULL` and `abc`, `13`, `10` would be equally valid? (That is to say, it doesn't matter whether or not the first row you happened to list is the row that gets updated?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't care which row gets updated, you can use `ROW_NUMBER` with an arbitrary order:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  *,
            RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY nrs ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
    FROM @Test1
)
UPDATE a
SET a.amtonhand = b.amtonhand 
FROM CTE a
INNER JOIN @Test2 b
    ON a.nrs = b.nrs
WHERE a.RN = 1;
```

The results are:

```
╔═════╦═════════╦═══════════╗
║ nrs ║ amtrqst ║ amtonhand ║
╠═════╬═════════╬═══════════╣
║ abc ║      10 ║ 10        ║
║ abc ║      12 ║ NULL      ║
║ abc ║      13 ║ NULL      ║
║ def ║       5 ║ 5         ║
║ def ║      12 ║ NULL      ║
╚═════╩═════════╩═══════════╝
```